# How to diagnose a problem in a Jet AFS-1000B Air Filtration system

Tags: electrical, repair, powertools

I've had a Jet Air Filtration unit (AFS 1000B) system for years and it's worked perfectly.  Recently I took out the filters for cleaning.  When I put them back the unit would not start.  All of the lights came on (ALL of them, including lights that should not be on at the same time) but the unit does not start.

Does anyone have any idea where to start in diagnosing the problem?

[image]

Comment: Are there any error codes in the manual?

Comment: Nope, none at all

Comment: When you put the filters in place they may push a tab or button which must be depressed for the unit to operate. This would be to insure that the unit is not operated without a filter in place. Remove the filters again and see if there is an interlock like this which is somehow not depressed the way the filters are currently in place. It might be that the order of the filters is important and the interlock is to insure that the filters are in the correct order. There could be *two* interlocks and one must be depressed and the other extended.

Comment: I took a quick look last night and didn't see anything - I'll take a more thorough look tonight

Comment: Did you try contacting Jet directly?

Comment: No word back yet

Comment: A safety interlock sounds logical since the filters were changed+. I was thinking the same thing.

Comment: I just checked - there are no switches of any kind near the filter.

Answer (score 1):

My AFS1000B air filter system started acting up after several years of use. In my shop I have it plugged into the same circuit where I have several fluorescent light fixtures connected. Over the years I have replaced several of the fluorescent fixtures with LED fixtures. My remote stopped cycling through the time selections and the fan would not run for very long before it would automatically shut off. I fixed this issue by removing the remaining two fluorescent light fixtures and replaced them with LED. So obviously it had something to do with Fluorescent fixtures, or perhaps my fluorescent fixtures got too old but anyway, it is working fine now, so for whatever it’s worth it might be useful to disconnect the fluorescent fixtures and see if the fan will operate properly